# using NSURLConnection didReceiveData for multiple calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get some design/code advise here.

I have an app which needs to call 3 apis of a web service. These happen in different views but I need all the information from these 3 apis to be in one object. So I pass an object from view controller to another and add data to it as I make the https calls to the web service.

I created a function called PostToServer, that calls the webapi based on the "type" and picks the appropriate URL to use for the post. But there will only be one didReceiveData call. I am storing the "type" of api in a variable in the object so that inside the didReceiveData I can parse the response appropriately.

Is there a better way to use the same NSURLConnection code to process multiple webapi calls? I am new to obj-c and so want to make sure I am using the language constructs properly.

Answer (score 2):

Their is one delegate of NSURLConnection class " - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response "  and in it their is a parameter response and this response has a property "URL" by which you can get to know that this response is for which URL request.
The "didReceiveResponse" method gets called once and then "didReceiveData" gets called, so you can make your check and logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use AFNetworking instead of NSURLConnection. If you need 3 requests to build one object you can pass this object from one connection to another and add missing data.

```
    NSString *urlString = ...

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": username,
                                 @"password": password,
                                 };

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/json"];

    [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        Person *person = [Person new];
        person.name = [responseObject valueForKey:@"name"];
        person.city = [responseObject valueForKey:@"city"];

       [self callSecondRequest:person];


    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


    }];

}
```

Method `callSecondRequest:` will add data from another request to the object.

Another option is to run simultaneously 3 requests which would share the same object.